# function added to ['#submit'] of user_login form is not invoked

Tags: forms

So, i have this project which has ton of custom code for authentication, cookies, 3rd party authentication & login tracking. Now, i have to enable TFA. Everything works after enabling TFA module except, it redirects users to /user after authentication success. They should be redirected to home. Redirection works fine if i enable TFA & my custom redirection on a clean Drupal installation. Just, it doesn't work when i move the custom module to the actual project.

I added a handler to ['#submit'] of user_login, but that seems not to be invoked.

By the way, how do you get a list of all functions which were called in order once a form is submitted? I added
`drupal_set_message(basename(FILE). ' : ' . FUNCTION);`
at the beginning of every damn function to see how the form submission flows from one function to another.

This is the output for user_login form to tfa_form

`customtfa.module : customtfa_tfa_api
customtfa_email.inc : __construct
customtfa_email.inc : begin
customtfa_email.inc : generate
customtfa_email.inc : sendCode
customtfa.module : customtfa_mail
customusers.module : customusers_mail_alter
Two-step verification code sent to your primary email id. Please check your mail.
customtfa_email.inc : getPluginContext
customusers.module : customusers_drupal_goto_alter
customusers.module : customusers_exit
customusers.module : customusers_boot
customusers.module : customusers_init
customusers.module : customusers_tokens
customusers.module : customusers_tokens
customusers.module : customusers_tokens
customusers.module : customusers_tokens
customusers.module : customusers_tokens
customtfa_email.inc : __construct
customtfa_email.inc : getForm
customtfa.module : customtfa_form_alter
customusers.module : customusers_form_alter
customtfa.module : _customtfa_afterbuild
customtfa.module : customtfa_form_alter
customusers.module : customusers_form_alter
customusers.module : customusers_tokens
customusers.module : customusers_tokens
customusers.module : customusers_tokens`

The function not being called above is _customtfa_submit()

What could be the issue? Is there any alternate way we to list all the functions called when a form is submitted? debug_backtrace only does a backtrace for a particular function.

Code of all modules/functions:

**customtfa.module**

```
<!-- language: php -->
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_tfa_api().
 */
function customtfa_tfa_api() {
  return array(
    'tfa_email' => array(
      'class' => 'TfaEmail',
      'name' => 'Email',
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function customtfa_permission() {
  return array(
    'require tfa' => array(
      'title' => t('Require TFA process'),
      'description' => t('Require two-factor to authenticate.'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function customtfa_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch($key) {
    case 'tfa_send':
      $message['subject'] = t('example.com: Two-step verfication code for login');
      $message['body'][] = t('Dear @username,', array('@username' => $params['username']));
      $message['body'][] = t('Two-step verification code for your login is: @code', array('@code' => $params['code']));
      $message['body'][] = t('Thanks,');
      $message['body'][] = t('example.com Team');
      break;
  }
}

function customtfa_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'user_login':
      array_unshift($form['#submit'], '_customtfa_submit');
      $form['#after_build'][] = '_customtfa_afterbuild';
      break;
  }
}

function _customtfa_afterbuild($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form;
}

function _customtfa_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $account = isset($form_state['uid']) ? user_load($form_state['uid']) : user_load_by_name($form_state['values']['name']);
  if(!user_access('require tfa', $account)) {
    $_SESSION['tfa'][$form_state['uid']]['login'] = TRUE;
  } else {
    $site_front_page = variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node');
    $form['#action'] = url($site_front_page) . '?destination=' . $site_front_page;
  }
}
```

**customtfa_email.inc**

```
<!-- language: php -->
<?php

class TfaEmail extends TfaBasePlugin implements TfaValidationPluginInterface, TfaSendPluginInterface {

  public function __construct(array $context) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    if (!empty($context['validate_context']) && !empty($context['validate_context']['code'])) {
      $this->code = $context['validate_context']['code'];
    }
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  public function begin() {
    if (!$this->code) {
      $this->code = $this->generate();
      if (!$this->sendCode($this->code)) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Unable to deliver the code. Please contact support.'), 'error');
      }
    }
  }

  public function getForm(array $form, array &$form_state) {
    $form['code'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Verification Code'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#description' => t('Enter @length-character code sent to your mail.', array('@length' => $this->codeLength)),
    );
    $form['actions']['login'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Verify'),
    );
    $form['actions']['resend'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Resend'),
      '#submit' => array('tfa_form_submit'),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    );

    return $form;
  }

  public function validateForm(array $form, array &$form_state) {
    // If operation is resend then do not attempt to validate code.
    if ($form_state['values']['op'] === $form_state['values']['resend']) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    elseif (!parent::validate($form_state['values']['code'])) {
      $this->errorMessages['code'] = t('Invalid code.');
      return FALSE;
    }
    else {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }

  public function submitForm(array $form, array &$form_state) {
    // Resend code if pushed.
    if ($form_state['values']['op'] === $form_state['values']['resend']) {
      $this->code = $this->generate();
      if (!$this->sendCode($this->code)) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Unable to deliver the code. Please contact support.'), 'error');
      }
      else {
        drupal_set_message(t('Code resent'));
      }
      return FALSE;
    }
    else {
      return parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Return context for this plugin.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function getPluginContext() {
    return array(
      'code' => $this->code,
    );
  }

  protected function generate() {
    $code = parent::generate();
    // store code
    $this->code = $code;
    return $code;
  }

  protected function sendCode($code) {
    $account = user_load($this->context['uid']);
    $message = array();
    $params = array(
      'code' => $code,
      'username' => $account->name,
    );
    $from = variable_get('site_mail', 'admin@example.com');
    $result = drupal_mail('customtfa', 'tfa_send', $account->mail, user_preferred_language($account), $params, $from, TRUE);
    if ($result['result'] == TRUE) {
      drupal_set_message(t('Two-step verification code sent to your primary email id. Please check your mail.'));
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem while generating your Two-step verification code. Please contact example.com/help'), 'error');
    }
  }
}
```

**customusers.module** (Other functions not mentioned here, have no code relevant to authentication)

```
function customusers_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code) {
  global $modal_js, $user;
  // Don't allow redirects in modals context.
  if ($modal_js &&
      !empty($user->uid) &&
      $user->uid > 0 &&
      ($path === 'modal/ajax/user' || $path === 'user')
  ) {
    $path = $path."/{$user->uid}/account";
  }
}
```